# how can i Hide element of iframe in wordpress page template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am displaying the iframe in wordpress page template. In iframe src i have pased the external site url. The Problem is that i am not able to to hide the logout link in the iframe.
    I have tried the below mention code :-

```
frame = document.getElementById("toolkit-iframe");
frame.document.getElementById("top-nav-links").style.display='none';

OR 

frame = document.getElementById("toolkit-iframe");
frame.contentDocument.getElementById("top-nav-links").style.display='none';
```

I have not got any success to hide the link of logout. Can anybody can help me. i will be verymuch thankfull.

Comment: You won't be able to access the iframe's content if it comes from another domain.

Comment: @Maerlyn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy I have read policy from wiki but is it possible to hide it using css?? And as it says cant be accessible thru another domain, same as my case but any possibility to do that?

Comment: Hacky solution, but what about placing an extra div with absolute position above the logout link?

Comment: There's no reliable and clean solution, only hacks.

Comment: And how about using a server side code to extract the domain?

Comment: @agieche I am not able to fetch id even then how can I place div above logout link? Can you please provide me more detail about your idea?

Comment: @Maerlyn Yeah I got your point, there is not a clean solution but any idea? Really giving me headache..

Comment: Proxy the site via your server, you can freely modify the DOM from your code in this case.

Comment: Place your iframe in a container div. Div gets relative positioning. Place another div in the container and set it to absolute positioning and perhaps a positive z-index. Set width and height and position of this hiding div according to the logoutlink size and position.

Comment: Thank you guys.. Let me try out your suggestions and get back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to manipulate the content of an iframe, that's not hosted on your domain due to security issues.

However, there is a "hacky" workaround for your problem:

Place your iframe in a container div. Div gets relative positioning. Place another div in the container and set it to absolute positioning and perhaps a positive z-index. Set width and height and position of this hiding div according to the logoutlink size and position.

Comment: Thank you so much @agieche, worked on your suggestion and its working great.

Answer (score 0):

You can not inject javascript into a page from another domain, even within an iframe.